# Postgresql xpath Searching for attribute and element combination

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

I was able to use Postgresql(9.4.x) xpath searching to match against an xml attribute or element. Is it possible to search the combination of both attribute and element value?

```
<name>
  <firstname>test</firstname>
  <lastname>user</lastname>
  <role num="10">admin</role>
  <role num="8">readonly</role>
</name>
```

I was trying to match admin role with number 10 in the above sample xml and below query does return TRUE for 8-admin combination as well.

```
select xpath('//role/@num="8" and //role/text()="admin"', '<above xml>');
```

Please suggest if there is any better way to matching exact index combination.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I was trying to match admin role with number 10

Try:

```
'//role[@num="10" and text()="admin"]'
```

Or if the `name` element for the admin is requested:

```
'//name[role[@num="10" and text()="admin"]]'
```

Comment: That worked. Thank much for your help.I need to tweak my query little bit as I was using this in where clause and my previous query returned true/false where as this query returned value.